# Retrieving attributes from a SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How would I get to the name variable given the object. `$obj->@attributes['name'];` would obviously not work.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [name] => Address
        )

    [value] => Address
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `$obj['name']` ?

For instance, if you take this portion of code :

```
$str = <<<XML
<root>
    <a name="test">
        glop
    </a>
</root>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
```

And these :

```
var_dump($xml->a);
```

Will get you :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'test' (length=4)
  string '
        glop
    ' (length=18)
```

And

```
var_dump($xml->a['name']);
```

Will get you :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
  string 'test' (length=4)
```

And casting this to a string :

```
var_dump((string)$xml->a['name']);
```

Finally gets you what you want :

```
string 'test' (length=4)
```

ie, you just use array-access to get the values of attributes.

Comment: Really should I cast it to string? OMG!

Answer (score 1):

For a SimpleXMLElement, you can access attributes using array access syntax

```
$obj['name']
```

Alternatively, you could type

```
$obj->attributes()->name
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just `$obj['name']`.

See their [basic usage doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) for more info.